# win11 cursor becomes invisible over (some) clickable objects

Tags: mouse

I must have hit some unfortunate keyboard combination: My mouse cursor in Win11 disappears whenever I hover over something click-able. When I move the mouse I can see it alright. Clicking works fine. I tried to play with mouse properties but couldn't find any option that solves it. Trying different hardware did not change the behaviour.

Comment: I do not see a setting on my Windows 11 machine that will do that. For a workaround, enable Show location of pointer (cursor) when CTRL key is pressed.